# Is there any way to add the intellisense support for java language in monaco editor?

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, monaco-editor

Any one know about the how to install java npm intellisense library? or any one know about the npm plugin command of java intellisense library. I want to use it for intellisense purpose in monaco editor